# Get date using day of the week

Tags: php, html, date

In PHP, how could I calculate the date of all days in a week using day of the week number and the current date?

My code:

```
 $daynumber=date("N",time());
 $date = date("l j F Y", strtotime("+ ".$daynumber." days"));
```

**EDIT:**

I have a scheduler script and I'm trying to get the date of every day of the week like this in a table:

```
 Monday   Tuesday   Wednesday   Thursday   Friday
 24-11    25-11     26-11       27-11      28-11
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think I don't understand your question properly,
but you can get the start and end date for a week with the current week and year for example..

```
function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
  $dto = new DateTime();
  $ret['week_start'] = $dto->setISODate($year, $week)->format('Y-m-d');
  $ret['week_end'] = $dto->modify('+6 days')->format('Y-m-d');
  return $ret;
}
```